# How to use Google Apps Script ContentService as a REST server

Tags: rest, google-apps-script

I have a service that creates a jSon response in Google Apps Script

```
function doGet(e) {
   return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(mcpher.getRestLibrary().serialize())
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

This can be found at [mcpher.com](https://script.google.com/a/macros/mcpher.com/s/AKfycbzLqpnQ2ey8CKAMmzchb2n2FU-aiae0iTKPzAOfAgEpxGwaJgk/exec)

When i run it at the browser, or the firefox RESTclient it gives a correct response. However when I use httpGET from within VBA, or as in the example below in Google Apps Script

```
function restTest() {
  var x = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://script.google.com/a/macros/mcpher.com/s/AKfycbzLqpnQ2ey8CKAMmzchb2n2FU-aiae0iTKPzAOfAgEpxGwaJgk/exec");
  mcpher.DebugPrint(x);
}
```

I get this response .. like a request to login

```
{"0":"\n<html dir=\"ltr\" >\n<head>\n  <meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex,nofollow\" />\n  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n  <title>mcpher.com</title>\n  <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n  <!--\n    // Keep login page from being trapped in iframes.\n  ... etc...
```

The script is set to anybody can access. Do I somehow have to authenticate - even though I'm running it from the same browser session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be set to anyone can access, including anonymous. Are you sure that's the setting?

Comment: Yes it is set to "Public on the web – Anyone on the Internet can find and view". When I access the source document directly, and I have signed out of google it requires me to log in. Does 'anyone on the internet' actually mean 'anyone on the internet who is logged in to a google account' perhaps?

Comment: That is the sharing list. That controls who can view the source in the editor and execute it. It is *not* the setting that controls who can run the app without viewing the source in the editor, which is what you need here. The setting you are looking for is in the "deploy as web app" dialog.

Comment: yep. I had that set to publish as web app,  "anyone". I never noticed the "anyone, even anonymous" option. That did it. Many thanks!