# Serving JSON from Google Apps Script as "user accessing the web-app"

Tags: json, authentication, google-apps-script

Trying to serve a JSON request made by a Google Apps Script as the user who is making the request. After thinking for a while, I realized that this cannot work, because the serving script needs to be authorized to run as the user who calls him, so the calling script would have to add some authorization info, which it doesn't, and I have no idea how to add that information (that is actually my question: which information to add to the http-request, and from where to get it).

But, nevertheless, when I call that server from within the browser, it works because the browser (in which I am logged into my Google account) sends the right info in the http-request to prove that it is authorized.

This question is somehow related to the question [How to use Google Apps Script ContentService as a REST server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475972/how-to-use-google-apps-script-contentservice-as-a-rest-server), but the answer given there is exactly what I don't want: The invoked JSON-Server should not run under my account, but under the account of the invoking user and use that users resources (scriptdb, drive, ...). 
So the question is: How to provide that information from one script run from a Google-account to another script, so that this other script can run within that account? I know that using gas-libraries solves that issue, but I would like to have it as JSON-client/server (Mainly to decouple dependencies). To add some code (to keep the Stack Overflow-spirit running), my client:

```
var scriptUrl="https://script.google.com/macros/s/paperlapapp1231231/exec";
function callIt (nm, args) {
  var a=[nm];
  for (x in args) {
    a.push(args[x]);
  }
  return Utilities.jsonParse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(scriptUrl+"?args="
       +encodeURIComponent(Utilities.jsonStringify(a))).getContentText());
}
function testFunction (p1, p2, p3) { // this is the proxy
  return callIt ("testFunction", arguments);
}
// Testroutine
function callTest() {
  var r=testFunction (9, "XXXlala", {"dudu":1, "dada":"xxx"});
  Logger.log ("r="+Utilities.jsonStringify(r));
}
```

My server:

```
function doGet(request) {
  var ret=null;
  try {
    Logger.log ("I got called with "+JSON.stringify(request));
    var args=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent (request.parameters.args));
    ret=ContentService.createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify(this[args.shift()].apply (this, args)))
         .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
  catch (e) {
    ret=ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
  return ret;
}
function testFunction (p1, p2, p3) { // this is the implementation
  var s="testing called p1="+p1+", p2="+p2+", p3="+p3;
  Logger.log (s);
  return {testingResult:s};
}
```

**EDIT:**

Worked out a solution, but requires a Chrome extension and an intermediate proxy server. See code at https://bitbucket.org/pbhd/gas-rest-server-as-calling-user

Comment: I'm also interested in this. But just a minor note, scriptdb is always a developer resource, it does not matter if the script is running as the user, there's only one db per script (and it counts against the developer account).

Comment: Yes, thats right and scriptdb is just a wrong example, but all the users spreadsheets and so on...

Comment: If the users are not accessing this API through a Browser, what your client application that is calling the REST API? (android, ios, windows?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This was not possible before, as my answer below reflects.
However, Google does allow this now, see `Execution API`
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run

---

Its not possible to do that from Google Apps Script. If I understand it correctly you are calling another Google Apps Script with urlFetch.

Since Google Apps Script doesn't have an oAuth scope you can't make an authenticated call. You can only call a webapp service published as *anonymous* thus will run always under owner permissions.

You can't do it with libraries either unless the initial script is also called with user permissions and not owner.

Comment: Note that some people rely on computer translations to read on the web, please be kind to use full words (i.e. not "u"). After all the goal here to help others.

Comment: Hmm. You understand it right. But: My stupid browser can do those authenticated calls, even after a reboot and a changed ip-address. So what is the magic the browser does which my json-client-script can't do? E.g. as a hack I could just take all the request-headers sent by my browser and let my client send them too (Tried to do that, doesnt work, but not sure wether I did it the right way)

Comment: That wont work either. U can call from the browser because it has the authentication saved. 1 that auth will expire so you cant reuse it. 2 that auth might be tied to the ip calling so you  cant move it to another caller ip.

Comment: Hmpf. Menawhile I got different knowledge: I copyed the cookies HSID, SSID and SID as found in the request from the browser, put it into a request made by an other host, and voila: it works. The problem seems to be the request made from within the script: some ugly buddy from within the google-landscape strips off these cookies. The other problem would be with this approach to get those cookies out of the browser. Ok, anyway, this would be an ugly hack, but I think it could be made working...

Comment: For security reasons I can see why google blocks you. There are other ways to do this. Consider calling an anon gas and pass it something secure that identifies the user. For example an access token for the plus email scope. On the gas get the email from the token thus now you know who is calling. Thats as far as authentication. Now for access, use that token but you need to call apis by protocol (urlfetch) not with gas libs. Been there.

Comment: Made a somehow different approach, see link in the edit of original post... But thanks and +1 for your help...