# How do I get the web app user's identity, but use the developer's permissions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a webapp that provides data from a database stored in a spreadsheet file on the developer's Google account. But the data it provides is stored in the Google account of the developer of the web app.

So basically, the file the data comes from, we don't want the user to have access to all of that data, just part of it. But in order to provide that data, we need to know who the user is.

If I run the script as Developer, I have access to the file, but I can't tell who the user is. If I run the script as the user, I can't access the file.

Is there a way to bridge this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the right conditions, you can provide this separation with another script that acts as a [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). Your web app then accesses the Proxy to retrieve data.

A Proxy script will run under the authority of the data owner (or developer), with full access to the spreadsheet. It provides a web service that is available to the consumers, who don't need spreadsheet access.

The "right conditions" are all about your comfort level with the security and privacy of your data.

- If you are within a Google Apps Domain (e.g. Education, Business) then your Proxy script can get access to the user's identity to verify their access. An example of such a script is the [AwesomeTable Proxy](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/spotlightonawesometableproxy), which is tailored to the that service, but can be adapted for general spreadsheet access control. Google takes care of all the authentication for you, and because your scripts are running within a Google Domain, you have the ability to get a user's ID. This is great for serving the data *within the domain only*; it does not serve the data to anonymous users. (In this context, anonymous means "not authenticated members of the domain".)
- If you simply want to secure access to the spreadsheet to the owner (or developer) account, but are OK with the data being publicly available, your Proxy can ignore all authentication & identification concerns.

  An example of a proxy script that *writes* to a spreadsheet is shown in [How to post to Google Docs Form directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633154/how-to-post-to-google-docs-form-directly/18725479#18725479).

  **Worth noting:** "Best practice is to ensure that JSONP scripts are read-only and only return non-sensitive information." <sup>[ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)</sup>
- And lastly, if your users are not within a domain but you still want to be able to identify them, you will need to implement your own authentication service in your Proxy, perhaps with a session token scheme so clients only need to authenticate once. This will require you to maintain your own database of users' credentials, and manage all the concerns that go with that.

  Once users have been issued a token, they would use that to request data through your Proxy. As long as the token is still valid (another concern), the Proxy knows *who* is making the request, and can fulfill it appropriately.

Within the limits imposed by Google Apps Script, those are the options I think you have. There are ways to work around the limitations, but they come with their own restrictions and caveats; [Serving JSON from Google Apps Script as "user accessing the web-app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223875/serving-json-from-google-apps-script-as-user-accessing-the-web-app) describes a hack involving a Chrome Extension and a Node.js server, for use at your own (considerable) risk.