# Google Apps Script: simple way to give a method a public REST interface

Tags: rest, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script, what's a simple way to make a REST API that calls a function in my script?

I realize REST's verbs (GET,POST,UPDATE,DELETE) require some decisions about how to map functionality to a javascript method, but I'm looking for the most general-purpose way to say "give me a REST interface for this method".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service). You write a function for the verb you want (`doGet` for GET, `doPost` for POST, others not supported) and then you can delegate to another function by passing its name as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to write a WebApp with a `doGet()` that accepts parameters, passes them to your function, then returns the function's output. (like Corey said... but I've written all this code so here you go!)

This does just that, for a simple calculator function:

```
/**
 * GET requests should be for read-only queries; they should not change the state of the server and its data.
 */
function doGet(e) {
  var output = '';
  if (Object.keys(e.parameters).length < 3) {
    output += doMath('help','0','0');
  }
  else {
    output += JSON.stringify(e.parameters) +'\n';  // Echo parameters - debug only
    output += doMath(e.parameters.operation[0], e.parameters.val1[0], e.parameters.val2[0]);
  }

  return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(output)
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

If you want to be a complete minimalist, this would work, with no error handling:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(doMath(e.parameters.operation[0], e.parameters.val1[0], e.parameters.val2[0]))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

To be effective in this model, your target function needs to handle its own error handling, and return something useful in all cases. Here's that simple calculator:

```
function doMath(operation, val1, val2) {
  // Do error checking for parameters
  var errors = '';
  for (var arg in arguments) {
    if (arguments[arg] == 'undefined') errors += "Missing " + arg + '\n';
    if (arg.indexOf('val') !== -1) {
      if (isNaN(arguments[arg])) errors += "Not a number: " + arg + '\n';
    }
  }
  // If we found errors, just report them
  if (errors != '') return errors;

  // Body of function
  var result;
  var num1 = parseFloat(val1);
  var num2 = parseFloat(val2);
  switch (operation) {
    case 'add':
      result = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case 'sub':
      result = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case 'mult':
      result = num1 * num2;
      break;
    case 'div':
      if (num2 !== 0.0) {
        result = num1 / num2;
      }
      else {
        result = 'Divide by zero';
      }
      break;
    case 'help':
      result = "Example:\n\n"
             + "  "+ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
             + "?operation=add&val1=2&val2=2\n\n"
             + "Returns '4'";
      break;
    default:
      result = 'Unsupported operation';
      break;
  }
  return result;
}
```

When deploying your web app, remember to make it available to 'everybody, even anonymous', according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11477708/1677912).