# Calling a google apps script execution api from PHP using a service account

Tags: php, google-apps-script, service-accounts

I'm trying to call a very simple google apps script from php using a service account so that only my server can access it, not users of the website.

Here is how I do. I create the script here https://script.google.com

```
function get() {
    return  ContentService.createTextOutput('get method');
}
```

and a new project is automatically associated when i save it.
Then I open `File > Project Properties` to get the `scriptId = MM8zQqofS1OIcnFiNSlm1CGEl5qMrMVBt`

I access the developer console of the associated project threw `Resources > Project Developers console` by clicking on the project link at the top of the popup displayed.

Then I click 'Activate and manage API' and activate the 'Google Apps Script Execution API'. I click on 'Credentials' and see that the previous operation automatically created OAuth2 credentials. But what I need is service account credentials. Then I create one `Add credentials > Service account` and download generated p12 file. I get the `clientId = 109160023321840004240` and `clientMail = account-1@project-id-uokwrcpiqeewhwvpdhb.iam.gserviceaccount.com` for this service account.

I go back to my script and share it with the service account email with read&write access `File > Share`. First of all i get an email in my personal mailbox which notifies me that

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

 account-1@project-id-uokwrcpiqeewhwvpdhb.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Then I publish the script as an execution API `Publish > Publish as an execution API` with access to everybody.

Now lets go on the PHP server side. Using the 'Google APIs Client Library for PHP' available here https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client I try to call my script function from PHP:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('109160023321840004240');
$client->setApplicationName('myScript');

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    'account-1@project-id-okwrcpiqeewhwvpdhb.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    [/*no scope nedeed for this simple script*/],
    file_get_contents('path_to_myScript.p12')
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$service = new Google_Service_Script($client);
$scriptId = 'MM8zQqofS1OIcnFiNSlm1CGEl5qMrMVBt';

// Create an execution request object.
$request = new Google_Service_Script_ExecutionRequest();
$request->setFunction('get');
$response = $service->scripts->run($scriptId, $request);
```

And here is the response I get all the time

```
Error calling POST https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/MM8zQqofS1OIcnFiNSlm1CGEl5qMrMVBt:run: (403) The caller does not have permission
```

If, when I deploy the script, I choose to give access to 'Me only', i get the following response.

```
Error calling POST https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/MM8zQqofS1OIcnFiNSlm1CGEl5qMrMVBt:run: (404) Requested entity was not found.
```

I would be so happy if one of you have an idea to help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apps script does not yet support service accounts with execution api. see https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5461

google said they are looking into it but apparently wont happen soon (based on google replies on google+ posts about this like https://plus.google.com/+MartinHawksey/posts/Zquix9XqzkK)

Comment: Ok Zig. Thank you very much to help me so fast so that I dont spent more hours to investigate were I'm wrong :)

Comment: I did but my vote will only appear when I will have 15 votes (sorry)
Would you know a workaround I could use so that my server can call my own script without prompting my website users for authorisations ? Would a server key work ? https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/key?type=SERVER_SIDE&project=project-id-uokwrcpiqeewhwvpdhb

Comment: look at the different apps script publishing options. you can make your own service.

Comment: The problem is that I want this script to be executed as "me" (owner of the script) or an account service I gave full access. I don't want to share it with users of my website and ask them for permission to run the script.

Comment: again, look at my comment above which covers your case. many other s.o. questions and official help cover this when executing as "me" with permissions anonymous

Comment: one example in s.o. that covers this is http://stackoverflow.com/q/11475972/2213940

Comment: Yes, I know that making my script accessible to anonymous or anyone logged in with a google account is possible. However this is not what I want. My script will be bound to spreadsheet data which I want ONLY my PHP server can read & modify. No way to have a public address like this https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzG7RVyM0s5pgvhI4K9-AM7P0GRmYkeX-iVB_rcaa-cpEOrM0BL/exec where anonymous or even logged-in users can pass parameters they want, for example. 
I know that the good way to do this is to use a service account but I'm not lucky. Thank you for your suggestions and patience anyway !

Comment: If it was possible to "bypass" them in this case, service accounts would  just be useless.
The only solution I see would be to login to my server threw oauth2 with my google account. Since I have full access to the script, my server could keep save my access token (and refresh token) in a database or file and use them to call the script, and refresh the access token before it expires.

Comment: since the script url is on your server, its unlikely anyone would guess it. add a password-like parameter and its even more obscure. its as hard as guessing the oauth token as long as you dont expose the url anywhere else.

Comment: Not a bad idea actually :) At least this would allow me to wait for service accounts tokens to work properly ! And I dont have to find a way to refresh access token on server side bofore it expires. Perfect ! Thanks